# Add property on lightning component for the community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I create a lightning component that display a custom object : an article, composed with a title, a description and an attachment (an image).
I use this component in the community builder and it's working, but I'd like to be able to change the attachment into the community builder, by adding some property in the component. For exemple, now if I want to change the image (attachment) I have to do it in salesforce directly...

Is it possible to add that kind of property in my component ? If yes how can I do it ?

Here is an image that show a component in the community builder and at the right we can see the properties in question : [image]

Comment: is this you looking for `implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"` ?

Comment: No I already did that : `<aura:component controller="myController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">` and I can put my component into a page in the community builder, but I also want to have some property that I can change in the community builder.... if it is possible !

Comment: you want to set your component attributes values from community builder ?

Comment: @sfdcweb I want to set an image as property, and then this image would be displayed in the component

Comment: dou -- image url  correct?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have a single component and you are using that to show all the menus .

Instead your each navigation menu itself will be a component and you will keep the URL configurable in the design file .If you need multiple items you will drag multiple of those components .

The other approach is if you are using queries to pull the results ,create a field at database to allow the app admin to input URL's there

Comment: I use a query in an apex controller which brings the results I need (title, description and image(attachment) ) but I don't really understand what you propose to do ?